# Android Service not using Wakelock acquired when screen turns off. How do I properly use one for background service

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, wakelock

I am trying to develop an Android service that runs when a button is pressed and stops when a button is pressed. I am trying to make it run even when the screen turns off whether by screen timeout or power button press. Pretty common concept I bet, but I haven't found a post that makes me realize what I am (most likely obviously) doing wrong.

Manifest has permission

```java
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Service gets started from fragment with boolean intent extra to specify if it should acquire wake lock

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), NetworkService.class);
intent.putExtra("Wake Lock", wakeLockBox.isEnabled());
mainActivity.startService(intent);
```

My Service creation acquires the wakelock with Partial tag.

```java
    private PowerManager mPowerManager;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private boolean wakeLockSet;

    // service doing its thing code here

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("Service", "Started");
        wakeLockSet = intent.getBooleanExtra("Wake Lock", false);
        // ...
        setWakeLock();
        // ...
        return START_STICKY;
    }


   private void setWakeLock()
   {
        mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "NetworkService::WakelockTag");
        wakeLock.acquire();
   }
```

Based on what I have seen in previous posts and from testing, the only way for the wakelock to be released is when the Service is destroyed.

```java
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // ...
        if (wakeLockSet) wakeLock.release();
        Log.d("Service", "Shutdown");
        stopSelf();
    }
```

Whenever my screen turns off, the service onDestroy() method is called and the service releases the lock stops itself. So I am confused about how the wakelock works with services that are supposed to run when the screen is off.

I have tried foreground services:

in the fragment

```java
// notification builder made earlier

Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), NetworkService.class);
intent.putExtra("Notification", builder.build());
intent.putExtra("Wake Lock", wakeLockBox.isEnabled());
mainActivity.startForegroundService(intent);
```

then the service creation

```java
    private PowerManager mPowerManager;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private boolean wakeLockSet;

    // service doing its thing code here

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        startForeground(400, intent.getExtras().getParcelable("Notification"));
        Log.d("Service", "Started");
        wakeLockSet = intent.getBooleanExtra("Wake Lock", false);
        // ...
        setWakeLock();
        // ...
        return START_STICKY;
    }


   private void setWakeLock()
   {
        mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "NetworkService::WakelockTag");
        wakeLock.acquire();
   }
```

Same results though. Open to any ideas and willing to share more info if needed.